# What test shall i use to see if one disease has any relation with other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, cross-correlation, categorical-data

I am using data from this [website (data is at the bottom of the page)](https://ssc.ca/en/case-study/can-google-flu-trends-predict-frequency-and-results-tests-influenza-and-other-respiratory) for a case-study. For the sake of question lets stick to any of FluWatch sheet say FluWatch-Alberta. I am coming up with a question of my own, i.e., if one disease has any relation with another one. What kind of statistical technique should I use here?

What i have thought so far

- The data is nominal so correlation wouldn't work
- Should I do some sort of cross classified observation? (I just read it somewhere not sure what it is)
- Or I am on wrong track and I can just do correlation/regression to check if disease A is related with disease B

Answer (score 1):

One can find correlations for this data, but not any causal relationships. There is a pronounced seasonal variation, which if ignored, would result in [spurious correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_correlation). I think you would need additional or different data to find any causal relationship.

Comment: okay thanks. so for just the given data, not any additional, what can i do to see if one disease is related with other? I don't have any other data so not sure what else to do. Assuming that we ignore seasonal variation, how can relate one disease to other?

Comment: For example, if you theory is that disease A can cause susceptibility to disease B, you need to know how many subjects get disease A when, how many also get disease B after what period of time, and you would need (among other things) to plot the times between getting diseases A and B to see if there is an increased probability at a particular time interval.

Comment: The "among other things" comment includes an adjustment or comparison for reducing seasonal epidemiology effects. For example, if for those who get diseases A or B but not both, disease A occurs sooner than disease B, it may be that the disease incubation times or otherwise epidemiology of disease identification times differ, such that that "A or B but not both A and B" frequency data becomes the control for the A then B test group.